# Intellij External Tools available variables

Tags: intellij-idea

Does anyone know where a wiki style list exists of all the available variable/macros are that intellij comes with out of the box?

I'm hoping to create a wiki style page that lists all the out of the box intellij variables (macros?) that can be used in External Tools.  I looked and could not find a list style reference to them anywhere, though if someone knows where such a list exists I would be glad to know.

Here's the ones I know of from seeing/using them in projects:

```
$FileDirRelativeToProjectRoot$
$FileName$
$FileDir$
$FileClass$
$ModuleFileDir$
$ProjectFileDir$
$Sourcepath$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you press the "Insert macro..." button, it will show you the list of all available variables.

Comment: can I create a macro, for example, one that returns method name that my cursor is inside its block?

Comment: To create a new macro, you need to write a plugin.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for this now, there is a list on JetBrains' website: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/built-in-macros.html

This is the current list as of Feb 20, 2024:

| Macro | Description |
| --- | --- |
| $AffectedModuleNames$ | The names of modules that are related to the current file, separated by commas. |
| $Classpath$ | The complete classpath of the project. |
| $ClasspathEntry$ | The entry in the classpath related to the current file. |
| $ClipboardContent$ | The current contents of the system clipboard. |
| $ColumnNumber$ | The column number where the caret is located in the current file. |
| $ContentRoot$ | The path to the content root to which the current file belongs. |
| $FileClass$ | The name of the class defined by the current file. |
| $FileDir$ | The absolute path to the directory that contains the current file. |
| $FileDirName$ | The name of the directory that contains the current file. |
| $FileDirPathFromParent(dir)$ | The path to the directory that contains the current file relative to a parent directory specified as the parameter dir. |
| $FileDirRelativeToProjectRoot$ | The path to the directory that contains the current file relative to the module's content root. |
| $FileDirRelativeToSourcepath$ | The path to the directory that contains the current file relative to the sourcepath root. |
| $FileEncoding$ | The encoding of the current file. |
| $FileExt$ | The extension of the current file. |
| $FileFQPackage$ | The fully qualified package name of the current file. |
| $FileName$ | The name of the current file (including all extensions). |
| $FileNameWithoutAllExtensions$ | The name of the current file without any extensions. This is useful when the file's extension got duplicated. It will remove any periods and everything that follows. |
| $FileNameWithoutExtension$ | The name of the file without the extension. This removes only one occurrence of a period followed by an extension. |
| $FilePackage$ | The immediate package name (not fully qualified) of the current file. |
| $FileParentDir$ | The name of the parent directory to the directory where the current file is located. |
| $FilePath$ | The absolute path to the current file. |
| $FilePathRelativeToProjectRoot$ | The path to the current file relative to the module's content root. |
| $FilePathRelativeToSourcepath$ | The path to the current file relative to the sourcepath root. |
| $FilePrompt$ | Shows the file system dialog to select the file. |
| $FileRelativeDir$ | The path to the directory where the current file is located relative to the module's content root. |
| $FileRelativePath$ | The path to the current file relative to the module's content root. |
| $IsMake$ | Returns true if compilation was performed with make. |
| $JavaDocPath$ | The JavaDoc output directory. |
| $JDKPath$ | The path to the project's JDK. |
| $LineNumber$ | The line number where the caret is located in the current file. |
| $ModuleFileDir$ | The absolute path to the directory where the current module file is located. |
| $ModuleFilePath$ | The absolute path to the current module file. |
| $ModuleName$ | The name of the current module file without the extension. |
| $ModuleSdkPath$ | The path to the current module's JDK. |
| $ModuleSourcePath$ | The current module's source path. |
| $OSName$ | The name of the operating system in lower case. It returns the value of System.getProperty("os.name") truncated to the first space character. So it doesn't contain specific versions, only the OS family, such as windows, mac, or linux. |
| $OutputPath$ | The current module's output path. |
| $ProjectFileDir$ | The absolute path to the current project directory. |
| $ProjectName$ | The name of the current project directory. |
| $Projectpath$ | The current project's source path. |
| $Prompt$ | Shows a dialog to pass an arbitrary string. |
| $RemoteProjectFileDir$ | The absolute path to the project directory on a remote server. |
| $SelectedText$ | The text currently selected in the editor. |
| $SelectionEndColumn$ | The column number where the selection ends. |
| $SelectionEndLine$ | The line number where the selection ends. |
| $SelectionStartColumn$ | The column number where the selection starts. |
| $SelectionStartLine$ | The line number where the selection starts. |
| $Sourcepath$ | The complete sourcepath of the project. |
| $SourcepathEntry$ | The entry in the sourcepath related to the current file. |
| $TempDir$ | The directory for temporary files. On Windows, it either returns the value of the %TEMP% environment variable or falls back to AppData\Local\Temp under the user's home directory (as returned by System.getProperty("user.home")). On other operating systems, $TempDir$ returns /tmp. |
| $UnixSeparators(path)$ | Takes a path as the parameter and converts all separators to forward slashes. For example, $UnixSeparators(\foo\bar)$ will return /foo/bar. |